# symfony admin generator forms

Tags: forms, symfony1

I use symfony admin generator to create a very long form.

This form is so long, that users hesitate to start completing.

I need to make small steps in fill in :
 example: First form: step 1 :   organization
          Second form: step 2:   name and occupation
          Third form: step 3:    solution

....
          Tenth form step 10:    memo

Every step has a submit button to save another portion/part of the form.

Do you have any ideas how to realize that ?
Thank you

Comment: It's generally a good idea to include your symfony version, since there are several of them, and they're very different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create 10 different forms (and actions in the controller), and when each part is completed (and validated) redirect to the next part of the form's controller action.

Comment: @ToderutHoratiu if this is the answer you end up using, make sure you mark it as such by clicking on the checkmark on the left of my post.